# "Null variable checking" in String

Tags: java, string

Generally, is there a difference between

```
if("x".equalsIgnoreCase(myStrVar))
```

and

```
if(myStrVar.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
```

in that the first will not cause a null pointer exception, but the second one will if in both scenarios `myStrVar` is null?

Comment: Yes. Why? What happened to you when you tried it out?

Comment: why don't you try it out in a junit test?

Comment: YOu've asked and answered the question already.

Comment: I believe you're talking about "Yoda Conditions"

Comment: still +1 for the question, since the rule "you should start with the constant to avoid nullpointer dereferences" is quite useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's correct. However, that doesn't mean you should always use the former ("safe") version.

If you are absolutely confident that `myStrVal` is non-null - meaning that for it to be null would indicate a bug - I would probably use the second form.

- I find it more readable (in the same way that I would write `if (x == 0)` rather than `if (0 == x)`
- If the value *is* null, it's probably better to go bang as early as possible, rather than continuing while in an unexpected state

So:

- If you want to have special handling for `myStrVal` being null, then perform a check for that first
- If you want to treat `myStrVal` being null in the same way as any other non-"x" value, use the first form
- If you want to treat `myStrVal` being null as a bug, use the second form

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, the answer is "yes". :)

Comment: His question is the answer. You have to reply in a question format :)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement that the second version would cause a `NullPointerException`, whereas the first one wouldn't, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a `NullPointerException` will be raised in the second scenario if `myStrVar == null`. You can't call `equalsIgnoreCase(String str)` on `null` but you can pass in `null` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, because the implementation is

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String anotherString) {
    return (this == anotherString) ? true :
           (anotherString != null) && (anotherString.count == count) &&
           regionMatches(true, 0, anotherString, 0, count);
}
```

This is a nice instance of the (Yoda Conditions-)rule: "you should start with the constant to avoid nullpointer dereferences".