# What is the difference between s.equals("") and "".equals(s)

Tags: java, string, equals

Firstly: what is the difference between `s.equals("")` and `"".equals(s)`?

Secondly: what would happen if I was to perform one of these functions? `"".substring(1)` or `"".charAt(0)`

Comment: For your second questions, what's stopping you from running some code and seeing? You can even run Java online at several websites in the browser.

Comment: Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9888508/1743880

Comment: If you can't run the second example, you can read the documentation which will tell you what happens.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the equals, there is no difference between the two equals variants when it comes to the result. However, the second one is nullsafe. If `s` would be null, the first one would throw a NullPointerException, the second variant would just evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 6):

First question: If `s` is not `null`, then there is no difference. If `s` is `null`, then `s.equals("")` will throw a `NullPointerException` while `"".equals(s)` will merely return `false`.

Second: Both of those will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

**First**:

The method of the instance of the class is called for both. So there is no difference in its internals.

It worth noting, however, that `"".equals(s)` is not likely to throw an `NullPointerException`. It is implemented as follows for the `String` class:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Second**:

```
"".substring(1);
```

This call would throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. From the Java's Documentation the exception occurs: *if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.*

```
"".charAt(0):
```

Also, it would throw the exception, and as stated in the previous example: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - *if the index argument is negative or not less than the length of this string.*