# My if statement doesn't work

Tags: android, service, if-statement

I am writing a service application in `Android`. In this application, I am receiving commands from Main activity using `onStartCommand` event. The `IF` block is checking a variable. As you can see in the picture(Debug mode), the value is "start" but the `IF` statement doesn't work and will redirect to `Else`. why?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with `.equals` will help you...

`String is not Primary Data type in java`

Always use `.equals() when you have Object` and `String is Object`

`==` is only for `primitive data type` and `==` in object compare your String Refrences...not value...

```
if(ReceivedCommandFromUser.equals("start"))
    {

      }
```

Comment: Thanks. So, would you tell me that what is wrong with current solution(using `IF` and `==` operator)?

Comment: @Kermia, see this (shameless link) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870985/if-condition-does-not-work/9870998#9870998

Answer (score 2):

When working with Strings in Java, use the .equals() method.

For example...

```
if(RecievedCommandFromUser.equals("start"){}
```

Should work.