# if statement not working to filter empty names

Tags: java, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If statement using == gives unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870985/if-statement-using-gives-unexpected-result)

Hi I'm using this code to add elements to my ComboBox, and I do not want to add empty elements, here's the code:

```
  public void elrendezesBetoltes(ArrayList<Elrendezes> ElrLista){
    int i;
    Elrendezes tmp;
    model.removeAllElements(); 
    model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(comboBoxItems);
    for(i=0; i<ElrLista.size(); i++){
         tmp = ElrLista.get(i);
         if(tmp.getName()!="")comboBoxItems.add(tmp.getName()); //not working
         addButton2(tmp.getSeatnum(),tmp.getCoord(),tmp.getFoglalt());
    }   
}
```

My problem is that the if statement is not working, it still adds empty names to my combobox. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `equals` method to compare Strings: -

```
if (tmp.getName()!="")
```

should be: -

```
if (!tmp.getName().equals(""))
```

**or simply use this**, if you want to check for `empty string`: -

```
if (!tmp.getName().isEmpty()) {
    comboBoxItems.add(tmp.getName());
}
```

Comment: @BalázsCsíkos.. You're welcome :) You should better use the last way, to check for empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals` method to compare string. By using `!=` operator, you are comparing the string instances, which is always going the be true as they(tmp.getName() and "") are not same string instances.

Change

```
      tmp.getName()!=""
```

to

```
      !"".equals(tmp.getName())
```

**Putting `""` as first string in comparison will take care of your `null` scenario as well i.e. it will not break if `tmp.getName()` is `null`.**

Comment: depending on the data maybe even `!"".equals(tmp.getName().trim())`

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()`:

```
if (!tmp.getName().equals(""))
```

Using `==` or `!=` compares string references, not string contents. This is almost never what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare Strings with "equals", then it will work

```
if(!tmp.getName().equals(""))comboBoxItems.add(tmp.getName())
```

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing for identity (==, !=) but each String instance has its own identity, even when they are equal.

So you need to do `!tmp.getName().equals("")`.

Generally it is considered best practice to start with the constant string first, because it will never be null: `!"".equals(tmp.getName())`

However, I would recommend to use apache commons lang StringUtils. It has a `notEmpty()` and `notBlank()` method that take care of null handling and also trimming.

PS: sometimes identity will work for Strings. but it should not be relied upon as it is caused by compiler or jvm optimization due to String immutability.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**String#isEmpty()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29)

```
if(!tmp.getName().isEmpty())
```

OR:

```
if(!tmp.getName().equals(""))
```

Always, check String equality with equals method. == operator only checks if two references point to the same String object.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if not on Java 6 and isEmpty is unavailable is this:

```
if (tmp.getName.length()>0)
```

Checking for the length is supposed to be quicker than using .equals although tbh the potential gain is so small its not worth worrying too much about.